# Create a non-uniform 2-D vector in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector

My objective is to create the following table (2D vector of namedtuples) in python:

```
     (0,0,1) | (2,0,7) | (1,0,1)
             | (3,0,1) | (4,0,1)
             | (5,0,1) |
```

As can be seen, table `T[0]` is of size 1, `T[1]` is of size 3 and `T[2]` of size 2.
All approches I have seen so far relate to the use List Comprehension but that results in a fixed MxN matrix. I am curious to know if I can use python to first pre-allocate the size of first-dimension (in my case 3) and then keep appending elements to each `T[i]`.

While writing in C++, I would declared a vector T of size 3 and continue to push_back elements to each dimension as need be in a dynamic fashion. However I am unable to find an elegant way to write this is python.

I am very new to python and my first attempt was to do the following (without the use of namedtuples):

```
 T=[]
 arr1=[0,1,2]
 arr2=[3,4]
 arr3=[6,6,7,8]

 T.append(arr1)
 T.append(arr2)
 T.append(arr3)
```

This led to the following result:

```
  >>T
  [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

However if I clear `arr1`, it shall be removed from `T` as well. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Comparing with what you *would* do in c++ doesn't justify a c++ tag.

Comment: Can you explain how you get from your desired input to your desired output? I don't understand the relationship between the code you provided and the table you showed at the top.

Comment: @pault Please consider the Table as single elements (instead of a namedtuple of 3 ints). The code is just a simpler representation of the problem, wherein each dimension of the vector varies in size. I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `[[(0,0,1)], [(2,0,7), (3,0,1),(5,0,1)],[(1,0,1),(4,0,1)]]`?  And you want code that helps you create it by specifying the number of sub-lists and the number of items in each sub-list then you just want to push items in from *back-to-front*?

Comment: _However if I clear arr1, it shall be removed from T as well._ Is this a gripe or a wish?

Comment: @wwii: I want to specify the number of sub-lists and then populate entries in each sub-list. Given my input, I do not know how many entries each sub-list would contain, but I do know the number of sub-lists.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: This is just an observation. Thank you.

Comment: I see. So coming back to your original question. What's wrong with `T = [[] for _ in range(3)]` `T[i].append(whatever_you_like)`? Btw. `arr1` is not removed from `T` it is still there, it's just empty.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you so much!! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

When you append `arr1` to `T`, you are not making a new copy of the `arr1` list. You need to make a copy of the list before you append it to `T` so that when you modify `arr1`, the list that you added to `T` is not modified.

To do this, use `T.append(list(arr1))`. That will make a new copy of `arr1` before adding it to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to limit memory consumption of the array only to the cells where you have entries *as long as you want to perform array-operations on the whole thing*. You can consider a masked array from numpy then:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
arr = ma.array([[0, 1, 2,-999], [3, 4,-999,-999], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
arr[arr==-999] = ma.masked
print arr

[[0 1 2 --]
 [3 4 -- --]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

Also possible using tuples as entries:

```
arr2 = ma.array([
    [(0,0,1), (2,0,7), (1,0,1)],
    [-999, (3,0,1), (4,0,1)],
    [-999, (5,0,1), -999],
], )
arr2[arr2==-999] = ma.masked
print arr2

[[(0, 0, 1) (2, 0, 7) (1, 0, 1)]
 [-- (3, 0, 1) (4, 0, 1)]
 [-- (5, 0, 1) --]]
```

If you need a memory efficient solution (and don't need vector-operations), your approach using a list of lists is probably the best you can do:

```
T = [
    [(0,0,1)],
    [(2,0,7), (3,0,1), (5,0,1)],
    [(1,0,1), (4,0,1)],    
]
print T

[[(0, 0, 1)], [(2, 0, 7), (3, 0, 1), (5, 0, 1)], [(1, 0, 1), (4, 0, 1)]]
```